# How to use font Awesome Icons with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.NET and I want to use font awesome icons in my project but I don't know how. Can someone help me with that please?
thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at this http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ ?

Comment: I tried it but for some reason it didn't work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the Visual Studio **NuGet Package Manager** to do the heavy lifting and configuration for you.

Go to Tools drop down menu --> NuGet Package Manager --> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

Then select the Browse tab at the top of the Nuget - Solution window. Search using FontAwesome. Select FontAwesome at top of search results, and select checkbox on project pane on right of window. Click Install.

Open your master page and drag the the font-awesome.css file from Solution Explorer panel into the head of your master page to correctly link to it. Now you're ready to use it and can look up the syntax [here](http://fontawesome.io/examples/).

Example:

```
<p>
   <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

After downloading font-awesome or get from any other project, you will find two types of files: the font and css.

1- Copy the font files (.woff, .eot, .otf) to the ~/fonts in your project main folder

2- Copy the font-awesome.min.css and font-awesome.css to ~/Content or css folder

3- Add this line "~/Content/font-awesome.min.csss" at the BundleConfig.cs located at App_Start/BundleConfig.cs like this

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                          "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
                          "~/Content/ekimba.css",
                          "~/Content/w3.css", 
                          "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                          "~/Content/site.css"));
```

[Check this image more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvOuQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Once you download the NuGet package (as noted correctly by @IrishChieftain), you can also add it to your web app like this..

In your `Bundle.config` file, update it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
    <include path="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the font awesome files, put them into a folder and place the folder inside the contents folder, create a bundle or edit an existing bundle and then normal font awsome tags and classes to add them to your views